# Sunspot Solr search on association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, search, solr

I have an Event model and an EventDate model.

Event has_many :event_dates and EventDate belongs_to :event

I'm trying to set up a Sunspot Solr search so that it will only return events that have an event date that is in the future.

I think I have this setup up correctly in my event model:

```
  searchable do
   text :headline, :info
   text :event_dates do 
    event_dates.map(&:event_date).compact.join(" ")
   end 
  end
```

But in my search controller I am having trouble with this:

```
class SearchController < ApplicationController
  def search
    @search = Sunspot.search [Event, Venue] do
      fulltext params[:search]

      any_of do
        all_of do
          with(:class, Event)
          with(:event_date).greater_than(Time.zone.now)
        end
        all_of do
          with(:class, Venue)
        end
      end    

    end
    @results = @search.results
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render json: @results }
    end
  end  
end
```

The line `with(:event_date).greater_than(Time.zone.now)` is producing the error: `Sunspot::UnrecognizedFieldError (No field configured for Event, Venue with name 'event_date'):`

I've also tried plural `with(:event_dates)` but that produced the same error.

The search works fine without the with(:event_date) line but I really need this in place for the search to serve it's purpose.

Can anyone with some experience of Sunspot Solr help please?

Thanks in advance.

Oh and in case anyone is wondering, this is my searchable block in the Venue model:

```
  searchable do
    text :name, :address_1, :address_2, :postcode
    text :town do
      town.town
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

I ended up solving this myself by modifying the searchable block in the event model:

```
  searchable do
   text :headline, :info
   time :event_dates, :multiple => true do 
    event_dates.map(&:event_date)
   end 
  end
```

The changes being changing the data type on event_dates to time (an obvious mistake) but also adding `:multiple => true` as an event has many event_dates.